# Selenium Scraping - Strange Code Behavior

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver

I built a code for scraping this website: https://www.interpol.int/How-we-work/Notices/Red-Notices/View-Red-Notices

The code should iterate throw every country on "Nationality" and inside the selected country it should iterate again throw the ages between 18 and 100 years; colecting the name, age and country of each person.

The problem: after the code run and finish its job, the resulting CSV file contains wrong informations. For example: there are 10 search results for Afghanistan in the website, but on the CSV I can find results from El Salvador, Suriname and etc. plus duplicated results.

This is my first project using Selenium and I can not identify why the file have so many error.

The code (the code is in English, but the comments are in Portuguese because I work to a Brazilian company):

```
# Instalar pacotes
!pip install webdriver-manager
!pip install pandas
conda install selenium

# Importar bibliotecas
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Instalar Webdriver
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Abrir aba Web
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
# Localizar website e entrar
website = 'https://www.interpol.int/How-we-work/Notices/Red-Notices/View-Red-Notices'
driver.get(website)
# Maximizar aba Web
driver.maximize_window()
# Inplicit wait de 5 segundos para renderizar a página ao abrir
time.sleep(5)
# Localizar botão e fechar aba de Cookies da página
search_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//i[@class='privacy-cookie-banner__icon-close']")
search_button.click()

# Criar listas vazias para armazenar a informação que queremos
name = []
ages = []
country = []
country_2 = []
test = ['Afghanistan']

# Encontrar todos os paises no seletor de nacionalidade da página e anexá los na lista country_2
select_countries = Select(driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//select[@id="nationality"]'))

for option in select_countries.options:
    country_2.append(option.text)

# Remover o primeiro elemento da lista country_2 (é um elemento vazio)
country_2.pop(0)

# Itera pelos países na lista country_2
for pais in test:
    select_countries.select_by_visible_text(pais)

    # Loop entre idades de 18 a 100 anos
    for age in range(18, 100):
        min_age_input = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//input[@id="ageMin"]')
        min_age_input.clear()  # Limpa o campo de idade mínima
        min_age_input.send_keys(str(age))  # Insere a idade mínima

        max_age_input = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//input[@id="ageMax"]')
        max_age_input.clear()  # Limpa o campo de idade máxima
        max_age_input.send_keys(str(age))  # Insere a idade máxima

        # Localiza o botão de pesquisa e clika nele
        search_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//button[@id='submit' and @type='submit']")
        search_button.click()


        # Localiza o elemento da barra de paginação usando XPath
        pagination = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//div[contains(@id, "paginationPanel")]')

        # Localiza todos os elementos <li> dentro do elemento de paginação
        pages = pagination.find_elements(by='xpath', value='.//li')

        # Obtenha o número da primeira e última página
        initial_page = 1

        # Verifique se há pelo menos dois elementos em 'pages' antes de acessar 'pages[-2]'
        if len(pages) >= 2:
            last_page = int(pages[-2].text)
        else:
            last_page = initial_page


        # Loop While para paginar todas as paginas do Website
        while initial_page <= last_page:

            # Try e Except para pular erros quando a página se encontra vazia (sem a presença de elementos para extrair)
            try:
                # Explicit Wait para esperar os elementos desejados aparecerem na página
                container = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "redNoticesList__list")]')))
                products = WebDriverWait(container, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, './/div[contains(@class, "redNoticesList__item notice_red")]')))
            except:
                pass

            # Try e Except para pular erros quando a página se encontra vazia (sem a presença de elementos para extrair)
            try:
                # Encontrar os elementos que desejamos exrair por xpath e anexar todos em suas devidas listas (criadas acima)
                for product in products:
                    name.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value=".//div[@class='redNoticeItem__labelText']").text)
                    ages.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//span[@class="age"]').text)
                    country.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//span[@class="nationalities"]').text)
            except:
                pass

                # Try e Except para evitar erros quando o prgrama chega na ultima aba e não existe mais o botão para uma próxima pagina
            try:
                # Encontra o botão que vai para a próxima aba (direita) e clika nele
                next_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//a[@class='nextIndex right-arrow']")
                next_button.click()
            except:
                pass


            # Parte final da paginação, diz ao loop while para somar +1 na contagem de páginas e ir para a proxima repetição
            initial_page = initial_page + 1


# Transforma as listas já preenchidas com informação em um documento CSV, utilizando o Pandas.
max_length = max(len(name), len(ages), len(country))

while len(name) < max_length:
    name.append('')
while len(ages) < max_length:
    ages.append('')
while len(country) < max_length:
    country.append('')

df_list = pd.DataFrame({'Name': name, 'Age': ages, 'Country': country})
df_list.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

I tried running some tests, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and run it. The problem is when you click on search, before server responds to your request, it load wrong data. Change your code and wait until the page loads:

```
    # Localiza o botão de pesquisa e clika nele
    search_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath',value="//button[@id='submit' and @type='submit']")
    search_button.click()
    
    time.sleep(5)
```

Hint: instead of scraping this website by nationality and search it by age to age, It's better to scrap all data page by page, and then, Do everything you want with pandas (filter by country or age or...). This is faster.

Comment: Man, you saved me at least a day or two of work! I appreciate your help so much, thank you!

Comment: @Gabriel: when you are able to, please consider "accepting" this answer to mark it as correct. To do so, click the check/tick mark to the left hand side, so it goes green. This rewards the answerer with some points, to encourage them to help people again.